# mysql prepared statement error: MySQLSyntaxErrorException

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, prepared-statement

I wrote select statement using prepared statement. Each time try to run it gives this error.
How am I over come this error?
my jdbc connector is mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar.
my code :

```
 public Main_add_ad_to getAdDetail(int ad_id) {
    Dbconnection db = new Dbconnection();
    Connection con = db.getConnection();
    ResultSet rs = null;

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Main_add_ad_to detail_to = new Main_add_ad_to();
    try {
    String selectSQL = "SELECT *  FROM ads_tbl where id = ?";

    stmt = con.prepareStatement(selectSQL);
    stmt.setInt(1, ad_id);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
    while (rs.next()) {

        detail_to.setCat_ad(rs.getString("cat"));
        detail_to.setType_ad(rs.getString("sale_type"));
        detail_to.setBrand(rs.getString("brand"));
    }catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Lands_cls.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
return detail_to;
}
```

error code..

Oct 01, 2013 1:23:23 PM sanin.lands.model.View_ads_cls getAdDetail

```
SEVERE: null
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

error is in this line

```
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(selectSQL);
```

do this way

```
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks.
It worked.
I referred this tutorial. Looks like its wrong. :(
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Answer (score 1):

```
executeQuery(your QUERY)
```

is supported while you all dealing with `Statment` object

```
 rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Is Statement is an interface?

Comment: Thanks.
It worked.
I referred this tutorial. Looks like its wrong. :(
http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: Statement "The object used for executing a static SQL statement and returning the results it produces."